# created button go out of preview pane border using resource editor

Tags: winapi, button, visual-c++-2010, windows-api-code-pack, resource-editor

I have come across a problem when i created a buttons at preview pane using resource editor (visual c++). The problem is when i try to move the width of preview pane the button don't adjust themselves to be in preview pane according to the movement of the preview pane width. (i mean when i reduce the width of preview pane they go outside the border of the preview pane in right side)..

Could any one please give me the solution to come out of this problem ??? I also want to tell you that i already have one photo in the dialog box which already adjust itself to be in preview pane according to the moving preview pane (I mean photo don't create any problem just the buttons i created go outside the border of the preview pane) ..may be because for the photo we have SS_CENTERIMAGE which keeps the image in center but nothing like this for buttons

Please give me the solution i am doing in Visual C++ using createdialog  using resource editor..

Comment: actually its the problem of resource editor..I think you have not understood the problem correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a window size is changed that window receives the WM_SIZE message, with the new size. Handle that message in your preview pane, calculate new button positions, and use MoveWindow or SetWindowPos to move the buttons.

Comment: Hii scott. when i do the way you told me.It create a problem that when i see the buttons in window explorer it is located in the middle of the preview pane whereas in outlook it is at the bottom.NO Doubt it remains constant at its place but what i want is. it should stay at the middle-bottom of preview pane at window explorer and outlook as well(I mean even if i reduce the width of the preview pane to half the button should be at the middle-bottom of the newly varied width of preview pane i mean button has to adjust itself at middle bottom according to the varying width of preview pane).thanks